# Shading a Region Between Two Dashed Lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn an axis with two dashed vertical lines:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    ymin=-6, ymax=6, ytick={1,3,5,-1,-3,-5}, ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=-2.3, xmax=2.3, xtick={-1,-2,1,2}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1, 1}{
      \draw[dashed,color=red] ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: #1, 0}) -- ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: #1, 0});};
     \addplot[red, mark=*] coordinates {(1,1)};
     \addplot[red, mark=*] coordinates {(-1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to shade the region between the dashed lines.

Comment: `\fill ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: -1, 0}) rectangle ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: 1, 0});};`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes!  If you add it as an answer, I can give you points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another possibility (different from what has been suggested in comments) using `\closedcycle`; the `axis on top=true` option causes the axis to be typeset on top of the filling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top=true,
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    ymin=-6, ymax=6, ytick={1,3,5,-1,-3,-5}, ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=-2.3, xmax=2.3, xtick={-1,-2,1,2}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
\addplot[fill=cyan,domain=-1:1,draw=none] {6} \closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=cyan,domain=-1:1,draw=none] {-6} \closedcycle;
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1, 1}{
      \draw[dashed,color=red] ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: #1, 0}) -- ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: #1, 0});};
     \addplot[red, mark=*] coordinates {(1,1)};
     \addplot[red, mark=*] coordinates {(-1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=13pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psframe*[linecolor=blue,opacity=.2](-1,-2)(1,2)
    \psset{linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed}
    \psline(-1,-2)(-1,2)
    \psline(1,-2)(1,2)
    \pscircle*(-1,1){3pt}
    \pscircle*(1,1){3pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]